# How do I configure prettier to format tsx file which use styled component?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components, prettier

Here is what is expected after formatting my file :

```js
export const StyledDiv = styled.div<StyledDivProps>`
    width: 56px;
    height: 30px;
`;
```

And this is what I get after formatting :

```js
export const StyledDiv =
    styled.div <
    StyledDivProps >
    width: 56px;
    height: 30px;
`;
```

I made some research to find the good configuration on Prettier but didn't get any working solution. I think I am missing something inside my config file on vscode.
Does anyone have an idea of what is the origin of the issue ? Do you have a solution ?

Thank you !

Here is my settings.json file :

````json
{
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
  "update.mode": "manual",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": true
    },
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem.
My .prettierrc file was

{
"printWidth": 80,
"tabWidth": 2,
"useTabs": false,
"semi": true,
"singleQuote": true,
"trailingComma": "none",
"jsxBracketSameLine": false,
"parser": "babel"
}

I deleted "parser": "babel" and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).